# Using unicode ℝ as commands \mathbb{R}

Tags: macros, unicode

I want to use a unicode character, say `$ℝ$`, and get the equivalent command `$\mathbb{R}$`. So what I want is something like

```
\newcommandℝ{\mathbb{R}}  //it won't work by default, of course
```

How can I do this? I know this is not related to use `unicode-math` package, because `unicode-math` package transform unicode to corresponding output, however I just want to use some unicode characters as a shorthand only (to increase the readibility).

Comment: »To increase the readability«: Maybe your editor offers replacement of some LaTeX-Code with unicode signs. You write `\mathbb{R}`, but after a second the editor simply displays a ℝ.

Comment: @Keks Dose I'm using TeXStudio. Does it have this feature? What editor do you suggest?

Comment: I'm using Emacs and I'm truly clueless about TeXStudio _and_ about writing math. I've seen some kind of replacement with org-mode in Emacs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ℝ}{\mathbb{R}}
\begin{document}

$ \mathbb{R} =1$ 

$ ℝ = 1 $

\end{document}
```

For XeLaTeX you can just remove the `inputenc` package, but in this case is simpler the David's suggestion of use `unicode-math`.

Comment: Thank you all. It works perfectly. And this increase huge readability of source code.

Comment: Why in the world would you use as an example the equation saying that the set of all real numbers is equal to the number 1? `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Because is not very exact, but is short. `:-)`

Answer (score 24):

If you are using

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

then just add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{211D}{\mathbb{R}}
```

With unicode TeX engines it is probably advisable to use `unicode-math` which would allow ℝ to be typeset directly, but if you are using 8bit math fonts still then you can use

```
\catcode`ℝ=13
\newcommandℝ{\mathbb{R}}
```

Comment: I'm using XeLaTeX. Can I directly write down `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{211D}{\mathbb{R}}` without any conflict?

Comment: Because if I use the `unicode-math` package, the fonts embedded in the pdf file will be changed to `TTF` format(I checked those by Adobe Reader).  And due to the strange behavior of Illustrator, the pdf file cannot be properly modified again due to the font matter. (I use illustrator to do further fancy decorations.) And I also want something like: whenever I type `☆{}`, it correspond to the command `\proof{}`, where `\proof` is a command defined by me.

Comment: What does `13` mean in your code?

Comment: @Eric but are you using opentype fonts for the text? Or are you using 8bit fonts everywhere (in which case why xetex?)

Comment: @Eric catcode 13 means "active` (so like `~` it is a character that expands to a command without needing a `\ `

Comment: I think the behavior when illustrator tries to open a PDF file is weird, I remember that I found it weird, and then experimented it many times. The result was: when AI opened a file with `type1` format, and if my computer has corresponding `type1` fonts, then these fonts can be displayed successfully, even I can edit them by the original AI text-tool. But if illustrator opened a file with `TTF` format(e.g. `LatinModernMath`), then the math fonts will be transformed to glyphs.

Comment: Well, I test it a few weeks ago, not sure what I remember is 100% correct. But I'm sure that I concluded then that using a `Type1` format is more ideal with illustrator. (By the way, I write my document in Chinese, so I also need XeLaTeX to typeset Chinese fonts.)

Comment: By the way, @David Carlisle I just found that you are the author of MathTime Pro/Pro2! :) I'm also using it now.

Comment: @Eric the latex support, not the fonts:-)

Comment: @Eric you should probably accept the other answer, egreg's package basically does one or other of the things I suggest here depending if pdftex or xetex is being used.